# VPS Ubuntu php artisan commands not working

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, vps

I can't run any php artisan command, it shows always the same error. I understand what it say but I can't execute php artisan migrate to make that table. I'm on VPS Ubuntu 16.04. Everything works perfectly on my localhost,this problem appears only when deploy app on vps

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8eA5.jpg)

error is:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cv.contacts' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `contacts` where `contacts`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

My routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::post('/', 'ContactController@store')->name('contact.store');
//eng
Route::get('/en', 'HomeController@index_en')->name('home.en');
Route::post('/en', 'ContactController@store')->name('contact.store');
```

Comment: Zoran, please show what error `php artisan migrate` outputs.

Comment: Probably you have put some code that use the `Contact` model in a wrong place, like in the root of your `routes/web.php` (instead of inside a closure or a controller`

Comment: The error is clear and you stated, you do understand it. So, is there a reference to `contacts` you are missing? Artisan is clearly looking for this table so either it needs to be created or needs to not be referenced. To better help, is this a pre-developed deployment or one you are developing from scratch? Can we see the relevant migration?

Comment: Zoran, it's hard to help you if you don't post any relevant code. As I said on my 2nd comment, you probably are using the `Contact` model on the wrong place (inside a route file or a service provider).

Comment: @EliasSoares I'm not sure which part of code to post,I'm not allowed to post images here (don't know why). All work perfect on localhost, this problem appears when I try to deploy my app on VPS

Comment: @Zaky I did this project from scratch. This problem only appears when I deploy app on VPS. On my localhost everything works perfectly.